# Get the total amount of music files by folders, albums, genres, etc. in Windows Library

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, libraries, music-management

How can I get summaries from Windows Libraries (especially from the Music Library)?

I would like to get the total amount of music files, but also the amount of music files by folders, albums, genres, authors and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your music collection in Music library using 'Arrange by' option ( e.g Artist,Album etc). Double Clicking on those grouped music collection, You can get exact information about total number of music files hold By that particular album, genre group.
Hope this may help you....

Comment: I got it ! So, It insn't in the Windows Media Player, but in the Windows Explorer. Is that the only way ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no option in library to get quick summary view of all files. Taking about WMP, yes there is an option to get quick view of all our music collection. Click start,type wmplayer.exe .now you will taken to Library view of WMP. here you will find many option to quickly sort music collection.
In left pane you will find music option, right click it, select "Customize navigation pane" and you will find most the option you looking for.
See this link For more info
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/getting-started-with-windows-media-player

Comment: I know this way, but there is no way to get summaries, like the amount of musics/files, etc. I didn't find it, which motivated me to ask here.

Comment: Should the same work in Windows 8 ?